# Symfony api with callback

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am having a problem while trying out symfony for my course projects

To make it simple I have an api route

Which allows you to create a subscription (fictitious of course)

In the controller of this route I call another url (that of the teacher to simulate the payment)

The teacher in turn calls one of my API routes to register the transaction made via a POST route.

Or the symfony server does not allow it.

Indeed it waits for the return of a route and therefore puts everything else on standby until the arrival of the 504 error ... or only then it triggers the insertion.

Anyone a little idea? :)

Cordially,

Quillian

Comment: Please, share code samples. It will help to support you in this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the code this is my custom controller.
The client request send me a post when i call it but symfony server just lock on response.
But for the response we need to insert the post ...

```
$abo = $this->abonnementRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
$response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            $this::URL. '/cardpay/' . $this::UUID . '/' . $id . '/' . $cardNumber . '/' . $month . '/' . $years . '/50'
);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$data = new stdClass();
$data->status = $statusCode;
$myJSON = json_encode($data);
return new JsonResponse($myJSON, $statusCode, [], true);
```

Comment: Did you find any answer to that issue, I face the same thing. It as perfectly working and all of a sudden I have this 504 out of nowhere.